# <input type="file"> extension filtering is not working

Tags: html

In my application i need the file chooser to only accept images with .jpg extension. The code used for this shown here

```
<input type='file' id="imgInp" accept="image/jpg"/>
```

But unfortunately the file input accept all the file types as input. Is there any other method for filtering the input ?

Comment: That will work for modern browsers (chrome, IE 10, Firefox, Safari) but for a complete solution you will need to either validate with a client side JavaScript solution or a server side language (PHP, .NET etc)

Comment: Thanks. But i am using updated version of chrome.

Comment: As per the answer below. 'jpg' is not a valid `MIME` type. See http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image

Comment: luke2012 Yes.I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **image/jpeg**

```
<input type='file' id="imgInp" accept="image/jpeg"/>
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/skRX9/